# mailx configuration for Yahoo SMTP

Tags: rhel, mailx

I am trying to configure `mailx` to send an email out using my yahoo email address. I am getting the following error when I try to send an email:

```
smtp-server: 550 Request failed; Mailbox unavailable
```

Here is my configuration:

```
set smtp-use-starttls
set ssl-verify=ignore 
set smtp=smtp://smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587
set smtp-auth=login
set smtp-auth-user=myemail@yahoo.com
set smtp-auth-password=mypassword
set from="myemail@yahoo.com (Batch Job Notification)"
```

In yahoo I did set up the `App Password`

Comment: your configuration is not readable, please format it

Comment: I just noticed that and fixed it